# canvas.drawBitmap and canvas.drawRect, the draw up object is not the same size

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I have a problem with canvas.drawBitmap and canvas.drawRect when i use canvas.drawRect everything works fine but when i use canvas.drawBitmap that when thing start to get strange. The size of the object drawn on the screen are not the same size for DrawRect as for DrawProcentObject. I haven't been able to find a problem with the math in my code so i guess the problem lies in how canvas.drawBitmap works.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what the problem is and how to solve it.

The width, height is the size of the object here, bmp is a bitmap.

```
DrawRect(canvas, width, height, x, y, Color.BLACK);
DrawProcentObject(canvas, bmp, x, y, width, height);
```

the width, height in this method are the screen resolution.

```
public void DrawObject(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bmp, int X, int Y) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, X, Y, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
public void DrawProcentObject(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bmp, int X, int Y, int SizeWidth, int SizeHeight)
{
    double x = width * ((double)X/1000);
    double y = height * ((double)Y/1000);
    double sizeWidth = width * ((double)SizeWidth/1000);
    double sizeHeight = height * ((double)SizeHeight/1000);
    bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) sizeWidth, (int) sizeHeight, true);
    DrawObject(canvas, bmp, (int) x, (int) y);
}
public void DrawRect(Canvas canvas, int SizeWidth, int SizeHeight, int X, int Y, int rectColer)
{
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(rectColer);
    canvas.drawRect(ProcentRect(SizeWidth, SizeHeight, X, Y), paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
public Rect ProcentRect(int SizeWidth, int SizeHeight, int X, int Y)
{
    double x = width * ((double)X/1000);
    double y = height * ((double)Y/1000);
    double sizeWidth = width * ((double)SizeWidth/1000);
    double sizeHeight = height * ((double)SizeHeight/1000);
    Rect rect = new Rect((int)x, (int)y, (int)x + (int)sizeWidth, (int)y + (int)sizeHeight);
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: I guess the canvas drawing depends on the screen density. I had similar problem with making image buttons - on higher density it looks smaller - on lower - it's bigger

Comment: since I was working with a BitmapDrawable, I used the bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() and bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() methods. These tells you what is the actual size. You can try to make your bitmap bigger/smaller (depends on the device density) - newHeight = (heightYouNeed / intrinsicHeight) * bitmapheight for example.